# Can we start the maven build from the point where it failed and skip the failed one

Tags: linux, maven, arm64, trino

I'm working on compiling Trino (formerly Presto) on an aarch64 architecture, and I'm encountering failures specifically in the trino-docs project. My goal is to proceed with the build process while bypassing the problematic trino-docs project.

mvn clean package -DskipTests -rf :trino-docs

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

mvn clean package -DskipTests --projects '!:trino-docs'